# Object key validation

Tags: javascript, json

I have this array of objects. How do i pass a list of keys in the `checkArray` function to validate the keys in one object?

```js
var test = [
  {
    date_issued: '2018-05-25',
    transaction_type: 'IMPORT',
    policy_number: '061/100/001052/2018',
    open_cover: false,
    endorsement_number: '',
    icc: 'ICC-A',
    insured_name: 'SAYONA STEEL LTD',
    insured_email: 'milmar@gmail.com',
    insured_tin: '103 286 883',
    intermediary_name: 'MILMAR',
    intermediary_tin: '100-714-078',
    goods_category: 'Mineral Products',
    country_of_origin: 'HK',
    destination: 'Mwanza Region',
    conveyance: 'SEA',
    financier: '',
    currency_code: 'USD',
    exchange_rate_used: '2262.37',
    sum_insured: '23302411',
    premium: '33935.55',
    VAT: '5176.609322',
    unit_of_measure: 'UNITS',
    quantity: '800',
    cover_start_date: '2018-05-15'
  },
  {
    date_issued: '2018-05-25',
    transaction_type: 'IMPORT',
    policy_number: '061/100/001051/2018',
    open_cover: false,
    endorsement_number: '',
    icc: 'ICC-A',
    insured_name: 'URHOME COMPANY LTD',
    insured_email: 'milmar@gmail.com',
    insured_tin: '132-209-898',
    intermediary_name: 'MILMAR',
    intermediary_tin: '100-714-078',
    goods_category: 'Base Metals And Articles Of Base Metal',
    country_of_origin: 'CN',
    destination: 'Dar es Salaam Region',
    conveyance: 'SEA',
    financier: '',
    currency_code: 'USD',
    exchange_rate_used: '2262.37',
    sum_insured: '54941202.98',
    premium: '58821.62',
    VAT: '8972.789492',
    unit_of_measure: 'UNITS',
    quantity: '2792',
    cover_start_date: '2018-05-15'
  }
];

function isKeyInObject(obj, key) {
  var res = Object.keys(obj).some(v => v == key);
  return res;
}

const checkArray = (test, key) => {
  let valid = true;

  test.map(item => {
    if (!isKeyInObject(item, key)) valid = false;
  });

  return valid;
};

console.log(checkArray(test, 'VAT'));
```

How can i pass the entire list of keys here to validate them? Right now i can only pass one key. I'm looking into something like `checkArray(test, 'VAT','destination','insured_tin');`

Comment: Since you already know how to compare the keys, I dont' get what's the problem that you're facing?

Comment: `if they exist and return true if they exist or return false if they exist?`  Could we start by correcting your logic here.. :)

Comment: @Keith i have updated the question

Comment: an array of strings and run this function until the array ends or until it returns false?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it easily using [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) function of Array

```js
var test = [
  {
    date_issued: '2018-05-25',
    transaction_type: 'IMPORT',
    policy_number: '061/100/001052/2018',
    open_cover: false,
    endorsement_number: '',
    icc: 'ICC-A',
    insured_name: 'SAYONA STEEL LTD',
    insured_email: 'milmar@gmail.com',
    insured_tin: '103 286 883',
    intermediary_name: 'MILMAR',
    intermediary_tin: '100-714-078',
    goods_category: 'Mineral Products',
    country_of_origin: 'HK',
    destination: 'Mwanza Region',
    conveyance: 'SEA',
    financier: '',
    currency_code: 'USD',
    exchange_rate_used: '2262.37',
    sum_insured: '23302411',
    premium: '33935.55',
    VAT: '5176.609322',
    unit_of_measure: 'UNITS',
    quantity: '800',
    cover_start_date: '2018-05-15'
  },
  {
    date_issued: '2018-05-25',
    transaction_type: 'IMPORT',
    policy_number: '061/100/001051/2018',
    open_cover: false,
    endorsement_number: '',
    icc: 'ICC-A',
    insured_name: 'URHOME COMPANY LTD',
    insured_email: 'milmar@gmail.com',
    insured_tin: '132-209-898',
    intermediary_name: 'MILMAR',
    intermediary_tin: '100-714-078',
    goods_category: 'Base Metals And Articles Of Base Metal',
    country_of_origin: 'CN',
    destination: 'Dar es Salaam Region',
    conveyance: 'SEA',
    financier: '',
    currency_code: 'USD',
    exchange_rate_used: '2262.37',
    sum_insured: '54941202.98',
    premium: '58821.62',
    VAT: '8972.789492',
    unit_of_measure: 'UNITS',
    quantity: '2792',
    cover_start_date: '2018-05-15'
  }
];

const checkArray = (test, keys) => {
  return test.every(item => keys.every(key => item.hasOwnProperty(key)));
};

console.log(checkArray(test, ['VAT', 'currency_code']));
console.log(checkArray(test, ['VAT', 'unknown']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `hasOwnProperty()` of object in javascript

```js
var test = [
  {
    date_issued: '2018-05-25',
    transaction_type: 'IMPORT',
    policy_number: '061/100/001052/2018',
    open_cover: false,
    endorsement_number: '',
    icc: 'ICC-A',
    insured_name: 'SAYONA STEEL LTD',
    insured_email: 'milmar@gmail.com',
    insured_tin: '103 286 883',
    intermediary_name: 'MILMAR',
    intermediary_tin: '100-714-078',
    goods_category: 'Mineral Products',
    country_of_origin: 'HK',
    destination: 'Mwanza Region',
    conveyance: 'SEA',
    financier: '',
    currency_code: 'USD',
    exchange_rate_used: '2262.37',
    sum_insured: '23302411',
    premium: '33935.55',
    VAT: '5176.609322',
    unit_of_measure: 'UNITS',
    quantity: '800',
    cover_start_date: '2018-05-15'
  },
  {
    date_issued: '2018-05-25',
    transaction_type: 'IMPORT',
    policy_number: '061/100/001051/2018',
    open_cover: false,
    endorsement_number: '',
    icc: 'ICC-A',
    insured_name: 'URHOME COMPANY LTD',
    insured_email: 'milmar@gmail.com',
    insured_tin: '132-209-898',
    intermediary_name: 'MILMAR',
    intermediary_tin: '100-714-078',
    goods_category: 'Base Metals And Articles Of Base Metal',
    country_of_origin: 'CN',
    destination: 'Dar es Salaam Region',
    conveyance: 'SEA',
    financier: '',
    currency_code: 'USD',
    exchange_rate_used: '2262.37',
    sum_insured: '54941202.98',
    premium: '58821.62',
    VAT: '8972.789492',
    unit_of_measure: 'UNITS',
    quantity: '2792',
    cover_start_date: '2018-05-15'
  }
];

const checkArray = (test, keys) => {
  let valid = true;
  test.map(object => {
    keys.map(key => {
        if(!object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            valid = false;
        }
    });
  });

  return valid;
};

console.log(checkArray(test,['VAT','intermediary_name']));
console.log(checkArray(test,['VAT','intermediary']));
```